# How to write while loop with completionStage which eventually returns CompletionStage without join?

Tags: java-8, completable-future, completion-stage

I have to write a function that returns `CompletionStage<Void>`.
This function can query paginated data(async operation, returns data wrapped in `CompletionStage`) and process them and query the next set of data until it finishes processing the entire set of data.
Is there a way I can use a while loop with the completion stage without using join?

```
public CompletionStage<Void> process(Input){
    while(allDataProcessed){
       queryDataAndProcess(This itself is async function)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show more of your code.  Where does 'allDataProcessed' come from?  What is the signature of `queryDataAndProcess`?

Comment: or better show code that we can understand and _without_ the need to get into all of your business requirements. But it surely looks like a loop with `thenCompose` should work, but it's impossible to tell unless you make a clear question

Comment: I got it working, used a thenCompose block to check if data is still there and recursively called the same function. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
public CompletionStage<Void> process(Input) {
     CompletableStage<Void> loop = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
     while(allDataProcessed) {
        loop = loop.thenCompose( unusued -> queryDataAndProcess(...) );
     }
     return loop;
}
```

The drawback of this solution is that it might create many object in memory.
To avoid this issues you could use the [IBM async utils](https://github.com/IBM/java-async-util):

```
public CompletionStage<Void> process(Input) {
    return AsyncTrampoline.asyncWhile( () -> 
        queryDataAndProcess(...).thenApply( r -> allDataProcessed )
    )
}
```

With Maven, you can add it to your project with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.async</groupId>
    <artifactId>asyncutil</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This library implements the [Trampoline pattern](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/trampoline/)